# Set the comparer for Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert to use for HashSet/Dictionary

Tags: json.net

I have a `HashSet<string>` that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` serialises to an array.

When I deserialise using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HashSet<string>>` I get a new `HashSet<string>` with the same values. However, the `Comparer` has been reset.

```
// JSON settings
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

// Create a case insensitive hashset
var h = new HashSet<string>(new string[] {"A", "b"}, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
h.Contains("a"); // TRUE

// Serialise and deserialise with Newtonsoft.Json
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(h, settings);
// s = ["A", "b"]
var newH = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HashSet<string>>(s, settings);

// Result is now case-sensitive
newH.Contains("a"); // FALSE
newH.Contains("A"); // TRUE
```

This is because `JsonConvert` uses `EqualityComparer<string>.Default`, which is case sensitive.

How do I tell it to use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead?

I don't want to include the `HashSet<string>.Comparer` property in the serialised data (I think it should be a simple array in JSON), I want to specify it at the point of deserialisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm) instead, when the hash set is the root object:

```
var newH = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(s, newH);
```

When the hash set is *not* the root object, Json.NET will populate it if preallocated unless [`ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObjectCreationHandling.htm) is enabled.  This allows the containing type to pre-allocate the hash set with the required comparer, e.g.:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject() { this.Collection = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }

    public HashSet<string> Collection { get; private set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could subclass [`CustomCreationConverter<HashSet<T>>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) and allocate the hash set with the required comparer within the converter's [`Create()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_CustomCreationConverter_1_Create.htm) method:

```
public class HashSetCreationConverter<T> : CustomCreationConverter<HashSet<T>>
{
    public IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer { get; private set; }

    public HashSetCreationConverter(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.Comparer = comparer;
    }

    public override HashSet<T> Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(Comparer);
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var newH = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HashSet<string>>(s, new HashSetCreationConverter<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Cheers (+1 and ans) that worked a treat! The example in my question is simplified, the `HashSet` is really a property. I changed it to: `public HashSet<string> PropName { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` and it worked.

Comment: @Keith - subclassing `CustomCreationConverter<T>` is also an option.  But I think preallocating the hash set in the constructor is best.